# How to access Tensor shape within .map function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

I have a dataset of audios in multiple lengths, and I want to crop all of them in 5 second windows (which means 240000 elements with 48000 sample rate). So, after loading the .tfrecord, I'm doing:

```
audio, sr = tf.audio.decode_wav(image_data)
```

which returns me a Tensor that has the audio length. If this length is less than the 240000 I would like to repeat the audio content til it's 240000. So I'm doing on ALL audios, with a `tf.data.Dataset.map()` function:

```
audio = tf.tile(audio, [5])
```

Since that's what it takes to pad my shortest audio to the desired length.

But for efficiency I wanted to do the operation only on elements that need it:

```
if audio.shape[0] < 240000:
  pad_num = tf.math.ceil(240000 / audio.shape[0]) #i.e. if the audio is 120000 long, the audio will repeat 2 times
  audio = tf.tile(audio, [pad_num])
```

But I can't access the shape property since it's dynamic and varies across the audios. I've tried using `tf.shape(audio)`, `audio.shape`, `audio.get_shape()`, but I get values like `None` for the shape, that doesn't allow me to do the comparison.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def enforce_length(audio):
    # Target shape
    AUDIO_LEN = 240_000
    # Current shape
    current_len = tf.shape(audio)[0]
    # Compute number of necessary repetitions
    num_reps = AUDIO_LEN // current_len
    num_reps += tf.dtypes.cast((AUDIO_LEN % current_len) > 0, num_reps.dtype)
    # Do repetitions
    audio_rep = tf.tile(audio, [num_reps])
    # Trim to required size
    return audio_rep[:AUDIO_LEN]

# Test
examples = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: iter([
    tf.zeros([100_000], tf.float32),
    tf.zeros([300_000], tf.float32),
    tf.zeros([123_456], tf.float32),
]), output_types=tf.float32, output_shapes=[None])
result = examples.map(enforce_length)
for item in result:
    print(item.shape)
```

Output:

```
(240000,)
(240000,)
(240000,)
```